# Erro declaração null - Unknown type name 'bool'

Tags: c, tipagem, booleano

O erro que está dando é nesta função.

```
bool tem_numero_na_lista(tipo_lista * aux, int valor) {
  while (aux - > prox != NULL) {
    if (aux - > info == valor) {
      return true;
    }
    aux = aux - > prox;
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

> error: unknown type name 'bool'

Comment: você incluiu  `#include <stdbool.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além do error: unknown type name 'bool'| tem alguns outros pequenos erros na função

```
while (aux -> prox != NULL)
```

Não irá verificar o último item da lista.

```
else {
  return false;
}
```

O `else` não é necessário, para retornar `false` caso a lista tenha sido percorrida e o valor não encontrado, basta colocar o retorno depois do `while`.

```
bool tem_numero_na_lista(tipo_lista * aux, int valor) {
  while (aux != NULL) {
    if (aux -> info == valor) {
      return true;
    }
    aux = aux -> prox;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Já tendo uma `lista` com os valores inseridos, você pode testar assim:

Ex: Verificar se o número 7 está na lista.

```
int valor = 7;
if( tem_numero_na_lista(lista, valor) )
    printf("Encontrou o valor %d na lista", valor);
else
    printf("Não encontrou o valor %d na lista", valor);
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que o operador seta `->` **não admite** espaço entre o `-` e o `>`; colocar espaços ali causa erro de sintaxe na hora de ler o código.

Comment: como testo na main @Lucas Trigueiro?

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando um exemplo de teste.

Answer (score 5):

Adicionou `#include <stdbool.h>`? Está usando um compilador pelo menos compatível com C99? Precisa.

Esse código tem outros problemas.

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).